# Is it possible from Go app to detect if CGO_ENABLED?

Tags: go, cgo

My Go app can work with MySQL, Postgres, and SQLite. At the first start, it asks what DB should be used.

SQLite works only with CGo. Depending on whether it is enabled or not, SQLite should be displayed in a list of supported databases.

Is it possible for the Go app to detect if CGO_ENABLED=1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [build constraints](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Build_constraints) to detect CGO.  Add these two files to the package:

cgotrue.go:

```golang
//go:build cgo
    
package yourPackageNameHere
    
const cgoEnabled = true
```

cgofalse.go:

```golang
//go:build !cgo
    
package yourPackageNameHere
    
const cgoEnabled = false
```

Only one of the files is compiled. Examine the `cgoEnabled` const to determine of CGO is enabled.

Another option is to add the following to a file that's always compiled:

```
var drivers []string{ "MySQL", "Postgres"}
```

and this to a CGO only file:

```golang
//go:build cgo

package yourPackageNameHere
    
func init() {
      drivers = append(drivers, "SQLite")
}
```